# Redirect on a wordpress action into functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, action, contact-form-7

I can not realize a **redirect** on a wordpress **action** defined in **functions.php**.
The action is the **wpcf7_before_send_mail**, this function in one specific condition must not send the contact form email.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_function' ); function my_function($wpcf7_data) { //redirect to another page }
```

Can you help me please? I am not very prepared on wordpress customizzation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you want to abort the sending of a mail and redirect to a page?

I'm not super familiar with Contact Form 7, but I think you should use [wpcf7_skip_mail](http://hookr.io/filters/wpcf7_skip_mail/) instead of wpcf7_before_send_mail, and then use [wp_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) to redirect to another page. So your code should look something like this:

```
function skip_mail($skip_mail, $contact_form) {

    // Put in ur condition
    if ($condition) {

        // The redirect (look at the attached url)
        wp_redirect($url)

        // Return ture if you want to skip sending the mail.
        return true;        
    }

    // Return false if you want to send the mail.
    return false;   

}

add_filter('wpcf7_skip_mail', 'skip_mail', 10, 2);
```

I havn't tested the code, but think it should work.

Btw, here is another example on using [wp_redirect with CF7.](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-how-to-redirect-after-submit)

Answer (score 0):

Since CF7 introduced some event in javascript you can try add this HTML into form:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
        location = 'http://example.com/';
    }, false );
</script>
```

In [CF7 page](https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/) you can find that.